# Error: Cannot change which global value set this picklist uses

Tags: jenkins, global-picklist

While deploying using Jenkins I get the error:

> Error: Cannot change which global value set this picklist uses

I have made a global picklist which has three values out of which one is default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GlobalPicklist xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <globalPicklistValues>
        <fullName>Planned</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </globalPicklistValues>
    <globalPicklistValues>
        <fullName>Done</fullName>
        <default>true</default>
    </globalPicklistValues>
    <globalPicklistValues>
        <fullName>Cancelled</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
    </globalPicklistValues>
    <masterLabel>Call Status</masterLabel>
    <sorted>false</sorted>
</GlobalPicklist>
```

I am using that global picklist in an object field.

```
    <fields>
        <fullName>Status_MDE__c</fullName>
        <description>If a call is planned with a future date, the status is set to &quot;Planned&quot; automatically.
If a call is created with todays date or older, the status is set to &quot;Done&quot; automatically</description>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <globalPicklist>CallStatus_MDE</globalPicklist>
        <label>Status</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Picklist</type>
    </fields>
```

Now when I pull data from Mavensmate the global picklist values are defined in the recordTypes of the object which causes this error.

```
 <recordTypes>
    <fullName>Regular_Calls</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <label>Regular Calls</label>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>CallStatus_MDE</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Cancelled</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Done</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Planned</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
</recordTypes>
```

I tried the idea mentioned here - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cJegAAE

Comment: Are you trying to convert existing field from regular picklist to global picklist? If so, you cannot. Try create new field as global picklist, copy data from the old field to new field, change all references to the new field, and at end delete the old (refular picklist).

Comment: No I am not converting a regular picklist to global picklist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how and why but when I changed the global picklist API name to match the field name. It worked!

```
<fields>
        **<fullName>CallStatus_MDE__c</fullName>**
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        **<globalPicklist>CallStatus_MDE</globalPicklist>**
        <label>Status</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Picklist</type>
    </fields>
```

Comment: Pretty valid! Mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Copado has a help article about this "issue" as well: https://docs.copado.com/article/wqw8pnn1li-cannot-change-which-global-value-set-this-picklist-uses-deployment-error - This is a Salesforce limitation regarding global picklists fields. The conversion of an existing field from regular to global picklist is not allowed by Salesforce. You will need to manually convert the field in the target org.